# Showing a representation is irreducible by showing that a degenerate subspace has codimension one.

Tags: representation-theory, hilbert-spaces

Throughout $\phi$ be a continuous character from a locally compact abelian group $G$ to the circle.

I'm trying to understand [this implication](http://books.google.com/books?id=g_K0HqWU538C&pg=PA101&lpg=PA101&dq=%22is%20a%20character%20of%20G%20and%20consider%20a%20function%22&source=bl&ots=YsVJdGQ212&sig=QPjSvMPNTpIC51QnfX8TcA_m3pk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TfBqUMXiBoWwqAHwjYHwBw&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22is%20a%20character%20of%20G%20and%20consider%20a%20function%22&f=false). Basically we want to show that a certain representation is irreducible. We know that the representation is of the form $C_c(G)/W$, where $W$ is the subspace of functions $f$ which are degenerate with respect to the norm $\langle\cdot\rangle_\phi$. We have that $\langle f,f\rangle_\phi=\left|\int\overline{\phi(s)}f(s)\ ds\right|^2$, and the authors assert that *hence* the subspace degenerate with respect to $\langle\cdot\rangle_\phi$ has codimension one, and therefore $C_c(G)/W$ (more precisely its closure) is one-dimensional.

How do we know that the degenerate subspace has codimension one? How does it follow from the calculation of the norm of an arbitrary $f\in C_c(G)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The degenerate subspace is the orthogonal complement of $\mathbb{C}\phi$ w.r.t. the inner product $\int\bar f g ds$. Whence codimension $1$.